# How to create Drools rule file for each user using Apache Storm?

Tags: java, drools, apache-storm, drools-guvnor, drools-fusion

We are making Storm application, there we need to create rule file for each user.it is possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can create the rule file based on user.

Me also done some R&D on this user based rule generation , in my scenario i have created the rule file as same as device_id , whenever i am getting the packet with that user i am loading the rule file with that name in the bolt.

Bolt:

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
                try {
                    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(new File("C:/IotHub/conf/"+deviceID))), ResourceType.DRL );
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                }
                KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
                kbase.addKnowledgePackages( kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages() );
               // 
               StatelessKnowledgeSession  ksession = kbase.newStatelessKnowledgeSession();

                ksession.execute(bean);
```

In my scenario , deviceId is the rule file name of that device

bean - is your java bean

Comment: yes i got idea but my question is there is no device id.where i need to call rule file in Storm in spout,bolt or topology?

Comment: Not spout , there are two way is there:1.you can load the drl in the bolt constructor 2.You can load in the bolt class as i mentioned above.

Comment: thanks a lot sir for giving reply now i got idea, i will do it.